# The practical differences between tenses

Tags: tenses

The McGraw-Hill Handbook of English Grammar and usage, p.81, says:

"The simple tenses (generally) refer to actions that take place at a single moment in time…The three perfect tenses, on the other hand, deal with actions that span a period of time."

This is complete rubbish, isn't it?

If I say "I walked to the station" or "I have walked to the station" there is absolutely no difference in the time span of the action. The difference is really in the narrative viewpoint.

"I boiled an egg"--"I had boiled an egg"…absolutely no difference in the time span.

And when we say (as the book itself details) "I walk to the station", we are generally referring to recurring or habitual actions, which is the complete reverse of "actions that take place at a single moment in time".

Comment: Generally means *in most cases* or *usually*. It also means "it is not 100% applicable". Can you edit your question and be more specific on what you don't understand? Your question seems to be too broad as it is.

Comment: I tend to agree with you. The thing that determines the span of time is the verb and indeed whole predicate. *I jumped in the air with glee* - is something that happened in an instant, but *I travelled to China* took a considerable amount of time. And it makes no difference if you use a compound tense. *She had jumped in the air with glee, the moment before she felt ill*. The jumping in the air still happened in an instant.

Comment: By 'complete rubbish' I meant that I think that it is not 'generally' true, but rather completely untrue. You can't say "Generally, gravity makes things move upwards." Like WS2, I don't believe the difference in tenses has anything at all to do with duration of action. What I don't understand is anything at all about the assertion.

Comment: Can you tell the difference between "I studied English" and "I have studied English"? What difference do you see?

Comment: Certainly not any difference of duration. The only difference would be in emphasis and usage. "I went to uni." "What did you study there?" "I studied English." OR "Have you studied any languages?" "I have studied English." Otherwise I can't think of any consistent difference in usage.

Comment: EXCEPT that people would tend to use "I have studied English" to imply that perhaps they didn't finish the course, whereas "I studied English" implies that you finished the course. I don't mean in the sense of CONTINUING the course, I mean in the sense of dropping out.

Comment: The description "actions that span a period of time" doesn't refer to the *duration* of the action itself, but rather whether the action remains meaningful currently. "I boiled an egg" takes place in the specific past; "I have boiled an egg" implies that the boiling of the egg in the past *remains* relevant; = "I have now and will always have the experience of boiling an egg."

Comment: "The simple tenses (generally) refer to actions that take place at a single moment in time." I think you're explaining the statement by completely rewriting it. I agree with your interpretation to a large extent, but that was not what they wrote.

Comment: @Chappo I understand what you say, but I am wondering if that really is the case. *I went to London*, and *I have been to London* both took the same amount of time - so no question there. However is one of them more *relevant* today, three weeks later ? Umm - I'm not sure!

Comment: @WS2: Suppose that London were suddenly renamed Lundun. A year from now, you'll be able to say "I went to London back when it was still called that", but not \*"I've been to London back when it was still called that": London's sudden non-existence will prevent the use of the present perfect in reference to it. (However, insofar as London and Lundun are the same place, you'll be able to say "I've been to Lundun, though of course they called it London back then".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's mostly rubbish.

To start with, the phrase "the three perfect tenses" is already pretty meaningless. I suppose the author is thinking of *had done* (the "past perfect"), *have done* (the "present perfect") and *will have done* (the "future perfect"); but there's nothing really special about those three as opposed to *having done*, *to have done*, *may have done*, *can't have done*, *should have done*, and so on.

Secondly, even if we set that aside, it makes little sense to talk about the semantics of *had/have/will have done* as opposed to those of *did/do/will do*, because *had done* doesn't actually have the same sort of semantics as *has done*. For example, whereas "She says he's lived to the age of 95" doesn't work if "he" is someone who's died, there's no problem with "She said he'd lived to the age of 95" even if "he" is someone who had died long before. This is because *had done* serves **both** a role along the lines of *do* : *has done* :: *did* : *had done* **and** a role along the lines of *do* : *did* :: *did* : *had done*, so "She said he'd lived to the age of 95" can simply be analogous to "She says he lived to the age of 95".

Thirdly, even if we give the author the benefit of the doubt and assume that (s)he was generalizing unthinkingly from *did* vs. *have done*, the key difference is that *have done* requires a relationship to the present, whereas *did* presupposes a specific past time of interest. This relationship to the present can be because the action continues to the present, which of course would imply that the action spans a period of time; but firstly, the relationship to the present is just as often that the action produced a state that continues to the present (e.g. "I've already eaten" meaning roughly "I'm not up for eating a meal right now"), or that the action is repeated multiple discrete times (e.g. "I've been there twice in the past three years"), and secondly, any event that can be described using *have done* will instead be described using *did* as soon as it no longer has this relationship to the present. So as you say, it's just a difference in the narrative viewpoint.